# Updating quantity for multiple products in shopping cart gives me zero

Tags: php

Hey guys am trying to work on. when a user updates the quantity on a product its supposed to multiply the quantity by the unit price of the product. Apparently, it can only work with a single product, if it is more than that, everything turns to zero when i try to update the quantity. here is my code please help.

```
    <tr align="left">
    <th width="62"><input type="checkbox" name="remove[]" value="<?php echo $pro_id; ?>"/></th>
    <th width="155">
    <img src="admin_area/product_images/<?php echo $product_image; ?>" width="60" height="60" /><br>
    <?php echo $product_title; ?> <br><br>
    </th>
    <th width="61"><?php echo $product_size; ?></th>
    <th width="62"><?php echo $product_paper; ?></th>
    <th width="67"><?php echo $product_grammage; ?></th>
    <th width="60"><?php echo $product_finish; ?></th>
    <th width="96"><?php echo $product_sides; ?></th>
    <th width="76"><?php echo $product_print; ?></th>
    <th width="105"><input type="text" size="6" name="qty" value="<?php $_SESSION['qty']; ?>" /></th>

    <?php 
    if(isset($_POST['update_cart'])) {

        $qty = $_POST['qty'];

        $update_qty = "update cart set qty='$qty'";

        $run_qty = mysqli_query($con, $update_qty);

        $_SESSION['qty']=$qty;

        $total = $total*$qty;

        }
    ?>

 <th width="112"><?php echo "UGX" . $single_price; ?></th>
 </tr>



 <?php } } ?>

</table> 
<table width="217" border="0" align="right" class="layoutCartTotal">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><h2><b>Sub Total:</b></h2></td>
    <td ><h2><?php echo "UGX" . $total; ?></h2></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="submit" name="update_cart" class="myButton" value="Update Order" /></td>
    <td><input type="submit" name="continue" class="myButton" value="Continue Shopping" /></td>
    <td><input type="submit" name="checkout" class="myButton" value="Place Order" /></td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: I dont see the `update_cart` in html

Comment: i have edited and added the update_cart part